# AutoMake conditional compilation issue

Tags: automake

I am trying to do this in automake

```
platform=$(uname)
ifeq ($(platform), Darwin)
    stmt = ...
else
    stmt1 = ...
endif
```

But I get

> error: else without if
>
> error: endif without if

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5):

- Remove the indentation so that all the statements start in column 1.
- With Automake conditionals, you first have to define a conditional variable in your configure script, like this:

  ```
  AM_CONDITIONAL([DARWIN], [test $(uname) -eq "Darwin"])
  ```

  then in the Automake file, do this:

  ```
  if DARWIN
  stmt = ...
  else
  stmt1 = ...
  endif
  ```

Alternatively, just write the if statement in bash script as the body of a rule in your Automake file.

Comment: I have the same problem.. but the ifeq etc just have to be copied verbatim to the Makefile! I don't want to use an automake conditional.  Isn't there a way to have automake copy a certain section verbatim to the output Makefile?